# Error using npm to install a forked repository as a dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, repository

I am getting `Can't install github:<repo>: Missing package name` error when trying to install my fork of a repository. The repository can be found [here](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/), but the part that I am trying to modify in my fork is a sub-project found [here](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha).

I have tried running `npm install <my_username>/puppeteer-extra --save` but it gives me the error mentioned above.

How can I make this fork install as a dependency in my project using npm?

This is not a duplicate question because I am getting an error and have to install a dependency from a subproject.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://npm.community/t/missing-package-name-error-when-installing-from-github/4471

Comment: @elethan I saw that but I'm not sure that I'm in the same situation as him.

Comment: I also wondered if you could “cheat” by giving the package a `name` in the package.json in your forked repo

Comment: @elethan Unfortunately I have already tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fix

The error you where getting when you posted the question: `Can't install github:<repo>: Missing package name`

This is now fixed by your commit : https://github.com/Joxroxagain/puppeteer-extra/commit/6f6cfe55dcf785f60bdc84c7b63e200e6d094cba and you should no longer be getting the error.

## New Error

However you might have tried to install it again, but now the error is `Can't install github:Joxroxagain/puppeteer-extra#6f6cfe55dcf785f60bdc84c7b63e200e6d094cba: Missing package version`

The fix of course is to add a package `version` to your `package.json`.

[image]